# Unable to achieve zero downtime during k8s nodes refresh/restart

Tags: kubernetes

I have the below setup:

- AWS EKS cluster
- Auto Scaling Group (ASG): min=2, max=4 ,current node=4
- Deployment: spring cloud gateway (scg), replicas=2, with liveness / readiness probe configured, with PDB (PodDistruptionBudget) minAvailable=1
- Deployment: process api (papi), replicas=2, with liveness / readiness probe configured, with PDB (PodDistruptionBudget) minAvailable=1
- Lambda: to drain node, trigger by node terminating event

Request flow:

> jmeter => scg (inbound) => papi => scg (outbound) => 3rd api

Note: scg works as inbound and outbound gateway here

Now the pods are running on the below nodes:

```
> node1: scg1, scg2
> node2: papi1
> node3: papi2
> node4: nil
```

When I protect node2, node3 and node4, and scale down nodes to 3, node1 is selected to terminate.

During the node1 shutdown, I can see scg1 was terminated first and its replacement was created on node4. After this, scg2 was terminated and its replacement created on node3:

```
node2: papi1
node3: papi2, scg2'
node4: scg1'
```

but during node1 shutdown, I can observe there are multiple 500 responses on jemeter and it lasted for around 15 seconds. The 500 is actually caused by the 503 for papi -> scg.

After this short stopage and before scg1' and scg2' are ready, there is no more 503. That means the 5XX error happens when scg1/2 is terminating.

Anyone have ideas where is wrong and how to achieve zero downtime during the EKS node refresh/restart? How can i avoide the 1X seconds downtime?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Spread pods for availability

Since you want to achieve *high availability*, it is good to spread the instances of apps to different nodes, e.g. in case the node unexpectedly is terminated (e.g. kernel crash) - and also to different AWS zones, since a whole zone might be unavailable during AWS maintenance. See [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/) on how to configure so that your instances are spread - to reduce risk for downtime.

E.g. you want `> node1: scg1, scg2` to be spread to different nodes, and preferably to different AWS zones.

### Disruption during termination

I am not aware about how the Spring Cloud Gateway is implemented. But make sure that it correctly handles `SIGTERM` signals, that the app is received when it is gracefully terminated, then it has a few seconds to fulfill requests, but it should not accept new requests during this period, and it can then shutdown itself safely when it is not handling traffic anymore. It might eventually get a `SIGKILL` and be terminated abrupt. You can control this period with the [termination grace period](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/abstractions/pod-termination/).

### Make sure the load balancer health checks

I assume that you have some Network Load Balancer in front of the SCG. Make sure that the load balancer only forwards traffic to healthy instances of SCG, e.g. it should monitor SCG and e.g. be aware of its readiness status.

### Client responsibility

It should be OK to have a few http 5xx errors, but not during many seconds as in your case. The client is responsible for doing retries of HTTP requests. Make sure that your HTTP API is implemented so that all endpoints are *idempotent* - e.g. so that it is fine to re-try requests.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Finally I figured that the long downtime (around 20s) is caused by the ingress (aws alb). Although the backend of the ingress route is k8s service, on AWS EC2 load balancer, the alb listener target is the IP of the k8s pod. Whenever a pod is terminating, its corresponding IP is no longer valid to access but on AWS target group, it takes around 30s to change the IP status from "healthy" to "draining", during this time ingress still route requests to the invalid IP.

Comment: for the ingress issue, finally found hint here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2366 and now the 5xx won't happen during pod terminating phase.